# Is there any JavaScript event that can tell us the when the main thread is idle?

Tags: javascript

```
document.addEventListener("pageBecomesInteractive", function()
{
   alert("page is interactive");
};
```

Basically, I want to execute the above function when the main is thread is done with parsing, evaluation and becomes free enough to take user inputs.
Is there any javascript event that captures Interactive event or any other way to do this?

UseCase: I have a website which contains multiple external javascript files like gtm.js, google analytics, some tracking js files, gpt.js, etc. My site's JS load event is getting called in max 2 sec but the page is becoming interactive after 8-10 sec due to the execution of all the above scripts. So I analyzed what is causing this delay and identified that Google Ad that is present in the first fold of the page is taking 1-3 sec(loading of this ad is taking time).

What I am thinking is if I load that Google ad few seconds post the interactive event, maybe I can save this 1-3 sec(that is costing me due to Google ad) in the interactive time.

I expecting the lighthouse performance improvement since my time to interactive could be less. It is just my hypothesis. Please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: It seems like you are looking for [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event).

Comment: Loading the initial page (html, css, script), blocks interactivity. Just listening for the load or domcontentloaded events should be enough to know if a page is interactive.

Comment: The thread is idle when you schedule a function to be executed and it executes. What problem are you *really* trying to solve here?

Comment: you can check this link hope it helps: > https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/requestIdleCallback

Comment: This is a case of the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) -- you want to do X (which we have no idea what is, since you say nothing about your actual problem) but don't know how to, but you think you'll solve the actual problem by doing Y ("how to execute function when "main thread" is idle), but you can't do that either, so you ask on Stack Overflow "how to do Y?". And Y, certainly, is a weird problem to be solving in and out of itself. How about you just describe what is it you are trying to do that seems to require you calling a function when "main thread" is idle?

Comment: Sorry for the abstract question. I have edited the question describing my actual problem statement. Please look into it.

Comment: window.requestIdleCallback is exactly what I needed, thanks @SubahanHerekar, this question should have never been closed